# Get data from Feed

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking-3, jsonparser

I am using AFNetworking for JSON parsing in my application.here is my response feed

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2017-10-24T13:05:28Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "diagnostics": {
            "redirect": [{
                "from": "test.com",
                "status": "307",
                "content": "test.com"
            }, {
                "from": "test.com",
                "status": "307",
                "content": "test.com"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get count and created field.
I have tried but I am getting nil values.

```
func getJson() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let manager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
        let targetURL = URL(string: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
        let dataTask = manager.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(_ response: URLResponse, _ data: Any, _ error: Error?) -> Void in

            guard let dict: [String: Any] = data as? [String : Any] else{
                return
            }
            print(dict)
            print(dict["count"] as? Int as Any)
            guard let dataString = dict["query"] as? [String : Any]  else{
                return
            }

            print(dataString)


        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Why not use Alamofire 4.0? It's made for swift: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire  Made by the same guys that made AFNetworking.

Comment: Yes I know but i am unable to set it up since i am facing some proxy issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you just forgot import AFNetworking?

Comment: This is my feed URL.Can you please let me know that how can i parse it?
                                                      https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Comment: {
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2017-10-24T13:05:28Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "redirect": [{
    "from": "test"
   }]
  }
 }
}